# cant add ImageView in a subclass

Tags: java, android

I can add an ImageView programatically from the main class. But I can't do it from a subclass.
When I try `ImageView iv = new ImageView(this)` I am getting an error
**ImageView (android.content.Contex) in ImageView can not be applied to *(...MainActivity.MySubclass)***

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity { 
...
class MySubclass
{
    ImageView iv;
    MySubclass(View v) // create an object from onClick method
    {
        iv = new ImageView(this);
    }
} // end of subclass

} // end of main
```

Comment: provide code what you have done

Comment: Why are you even adding image view in subclass?

Comment: If you are new to android, [this is great learning stuff](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki)

Comment: im not such a new. I am about to publish my 2nd app on play store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't have a code posted, I have to guess.

Instead of using `this` keyword, try to use `MainActivity.this`.

If you have a subclass in your activity, you will most likely use the context of the running activity.

Comment: yep this is what I was asking for. Thanks,